# split_dataset_to_data_and_labels in qiskit not working correctly

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am using source code of split_dataset_to_data_and_labels as I am unable to install qiskit-aqua because of error. But in that source code, "keys" is not being identified. I am using qiskit's tutorials as I am learning, and code I wrote from it, is-:

```
feature_dim = 2
training_dataset_size = 20
testing_dataset_size = 10
shot = 10000
sample_Total, training_input, test_input, class_labels = ad_hoc_data(training_size=training_dataset_size,
                                                                    test_size=testing_dataset_size,
                                                                    gap=0.3,
                                                                    n=feature_dim,
                                                                    plot_data=True)
datapoints, class_to_label = split_dataset_to_data_and_labels(test_input)
print(class_to_label)
```

It is giving this error-:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 10>()
      4 shot = 10000
      5 sample_Total, training_input, test_input, class_labels = ad_hoc_data(training_size=training_dataset_size,
      6                                                                     test_size=testing_dataset_size,
      7                                                                     gap=0.3,
      8                                                                     n=feature_dim,
      9                                                                     plot_data=True)
---> 10 datapoints, class_to_label = split_dataset_to_data_and_labels(test_input)
     11 print(class_to_label)

Input In [4], in split_dataset_to_data_and_labels(dataset, class_names)
     22 labels = []
     23 if class_names is None:
---> 24     sorted_classes_name = sorted(list(dataset.keys()))
     25     class_to_label = {k: idx for idx, k in enumerate(sorted_classes_name)}
     26 else:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

The link to source code, I am using is https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/main/qiskit/aqua/utils/dataset_helper.py .
I found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66591189/can-you-help-me-in-this-error-attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-att that flags can be used but it also gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qiskit Aqua (now deprecated) contains the function `ad_hoc_data`<sup>[[1]](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.19/stubs/qiskit.ml.datasets.ad_hoc_data.html)</sup> which returns
`sample_total, training_input, test_input, class_labels`. When using it, you need to call `split_dataset_to_data_and_labels` to split the retuned dataset to data and labels.

On the other hand, Qiskit Machine Learning contains a new version of `ad_hoc_data`<sup>[[2]](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.datasets.ad_hoc_data.html)</sup> whcih returns `training_features, training_labels, test_features, test_labels`. There is no need to use `split_dataset_to_data_and_labels` with it.

It looks like you are using functions from old `qiskit.ml` with functions from new `qiskit_machine_learning`. You shouldn't.
Try to follow the new Qiskit Machine Learning tutorials ([here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/index.html)) to avoid these errors. The new version of `ad_hoc_data` is used in [this](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/03_quantum_kernel.html) tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for your help.